# ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> doesnt work propetly

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, parse-platform

I am a new android developer and Im making an app with Parse as my database.
Parse offers it's own Adapter to listview which is called 'ParseQueryAdapter'.
In my app I want to show the user a list of users in AddingFriendsActivity(by using ParseQueryAdapter),in which he/she will be able to search in a EditText a username of a PArseUser and click the Serch Button to see a list of user name and thier profile picture which they will be able to add to thier friends list.
Each of my ParseUsers has:
1) JSONArray by the key:"friendsarray"
2) User Name by the key: "username"
and each has a uniqe Id and more, but it is irrelevant.
I have watched and read almost evrey ParseQueryAdapter tutorils, yet Im still not able to find out why my AddingFriendsActivity doesnt run..If you Find any problem, or you have a suggestions how to fix this, Ill be glad.
Here is a code of my Activity:

```
public class AddingFriendsActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener  {

ListView listview; 
Button btnsearch;
TextView tvname;

ParseQuery<ParseUser> query;//query that finds the searched user (that is not already a friend of the currentUSer)
ParseUser currentUser;//The currentUser
ArrayList<ParseUser> listUsers;//all users
ParseUser clickedUser;//user in  the list view that has been clicked


ArrayList<String> listFriendsNames;// list of ONLY USERNAMES of friends from the array friends of the currentUser

QueryFactory<ParseUser> factory;

ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adding_friends);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());


    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addingfriends_listview);

    currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    btnsearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addingfriends_btnsearch);
    tvname=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addingfriends_etusername);
    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(AddingFriendsActivity.this);

    JSONArray jArray=currentUser.getJSONArray("friendsarray");// list of friends from the arrayfrinds of the currentUser

    if(jArray!=null)
    {
    ParseUser p = new ParseUser();
    listFriendsNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
      {

        try {
            p=(ParseUser) jArray.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           listFriendsNames.add(p.getUsername());
      } 
    }
    refreshTheAdapter();
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

refreshTheAdapter();
    }

```
    public void refreshTheAdapter() 
{ 
     factory= new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() 
     {
                public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() 
                { 
                query =ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereStartsWith("username",tvname.getText().toString());
                if (listFriendsNames!=null)
                query.whereNotContainedIn("useranme",listFriendsNames);
                query.orderByAscending("useranme");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() 
                {       
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) 
                    {
                    if (e == null)      listUsers=(ArrayList<ParseUser>) objects;
                    }
              });   

                 return query;
                }
    };

    if (factory!=null)
    objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully();


}


public void objectsWereRetrievedSuccessfully()
{


    adapter= new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser>(this, factory);
    adapter.setTextKey("username");
    //adapter.setImageKey("selfphoto");
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    clickedUser=listUsers.get(position);

}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Do you want to add"+clickedUser.getUsername()+"as a new friend?");
    builder.setMessage("If you really know this user,add him");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add Friend", new OkOnClickListener());
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancle" , new CancelOnClickListener());      
    dialog=builder.create();
    dialog.show();

        break;


    default:
        break;
    }


    return super.onCreateDialog(id);

}


public class OkOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        currentUser.addUnique("friendsarray",clickedUser);
        listFriendsNames.add(clickedUser.getUsername());
        tvname.setText("");
    }

}
public class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

}

here is my xml file of this activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AddingFriendsActivity" 
 android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/addingfriends_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Add New Friends !!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addingfriends_etusername"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Search for friends" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addingfriends_btnsearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
     />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/addingfriends_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:visibility="visible">
</ListView>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "doesnt run"? Please explain the expected vs the experienced behavior.

Comment: Oh okay, Im new here, thaks for the guidance. As the user clicks to move to the AddingFriendsActivity my project fails and a stops. The logCat and ErrorLog dont show any problem.

Comment: If it crashes, youll need to provide the stack trace. Without any details on what is happening, how can we help?

Comment: Oh okay, just a second.

Comment: Here is a stack trace in console,There isnt any problem shown from launnching till crashing:
[2014-04-28 18:35:41 - ParseStarterProject] Starting activity com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-04-28 18:35:44 - ParseStarterProject] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.parse.starter/.ParseStarterProjectActivity }

Cant see here any problem. Where can I see a stack trace which shows  where it fails?

Comment: It should give you an error somewhere in the StackTrace - ive seen Null Pointer Exceptions happen with ParseQueryAdapter ... ???